# What should I do to make generated avatars different for anonymous comments?

Tags: comments, user-registration, avatar

All the comments on my website are anonymous and without registration. To post a comment you have to fill the fields name (not obligatorily) and the text of your comment (obligatorily).

I have the problem with the avatars. All of them are generated the same.

What should I do to make them different?

Comment: Do you want to differentiate Registered users *without* avatars from Anonymous visitors?

Comment: No, I don't have registered users :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to customize the default avatar:

1. Add a new default avatar to *Settings/Discussion*.
2. Change the output of `get_avatar()`.

Let’s start with the first option; this processes slightly faster.

### Add a new default avatar to *Settings/Discussion*

There is a filter `'avatar_defaults'`. You can add more avatars here.
You get an array of default images where the key is an URL and the value the visible name.

#### Sample Code

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpse_58373_kitten_avatar' );

/**
 * Add a new default avatar.
 *
 * @param  array $avatar_defaults Key = URL, Value = Visible name.
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_58373_kitten_avatar( $avatar_defaults )
{
    $avatar_defaults['http://placekitten.com/32/32'] = 'Kitty';

    return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

### Change the output of `get_avatar()`.

`get_avatar()` searches in an option named `'avatar_default'` first. We can hook into `'pre_option_avatar_default'` and return a custom (random) URL.

#### Sample code

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_avatar_default', 'wpse_58373_custom_default_avatar');

/**
 * Return a random image URL
 */
function wpse_58373_custom_default_avatar()
{
    /* We use images from WP here, you should change this and put some default
     * images into your theme or plugin directory.
     */
    $base_url = admin_url( 'images' ) . '/';
    $images   = array ( 'wp-logo-vs.png', 'wpspin_dark.gif', 'yes.png' );
    $rand     = rand( 0, ( count( $images ) - 1 ) );

    return $base_url . $images[ $rand ];
}
```

#### Result

[image]

As you can see – you should return an image with a size that matches your theme’s avatar size. :)

Comment: Thank you! Instead of placekitten.com I will try `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{MD5}.jpg?s=32&d=identicon`

Answer (score 1):

Re: random avatar generation, this was an extremely helpful answer and worked a treat with one minor modification - the function in question required an argument to pass through.  Without the argument, the code returned included a jumble of html which included both the desired url of the image, as well as url of the default icon from gravitar.  I changed it from this:

`wpse_58373_custom_default_avatar`()

to this:

```
wpse_58373_custom_default_avatar($value)
```

and that seemed to generate the image url without the jumble. For ease of use, the final code, with the addition of get_template_directory_uri () to target the theme rather than the admin folder, and some tucking away of variables was:

```
// Random Avatar

add_filter( 'pre_option_avatar_default', 'mind_bullets_default_avatar' );

function mind_bullets_default_avatar ( $value ) {

  $tix_array = array ( 'Amer_Cyborg.jpg', 'Die_hard_3.jpg', 'Thing.jpg' );

// Include randomizer in url generator
    return get_template_directory_uri().'/images/Avatars/'.$tix_array [rand( 0, ( count( $tix_array ) - 1 ) )]; 

}
```

Hope to allow users to choose their own soon, but for those who just want to comment, it keeps the look of the site consistent.

Answer (score -2):

To add to what already has been said, I suggest using the plugin "code snippets"

This way, your modifications to the internals of wordpress will not collide with updates, and you can actually manage them (activate, deactivate, export them... )

I set up a little tutorial to create custom random avatars using info from this question and Code Snippets

[custom random avatars tutorial](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/31/custom-random-avatars-in-wordpress/)

This is how it looks

[image: example_random_avatars]

The code I used is pretty simple

```
// Random Chameleon Avatar

add_filter( 'pre_option_avatar_default', 'chameleon_default_avatar' );


function chameleon_default_avatar ( $value )
{
  return admin_url( 'images' ) . '/cham_avatars/cham_avatar'.rand( 0 , 13 ).'.jpg';
}
```

Comment: That code snippet doesn't colide with WordPress core updates; I don't get your point about using a third party plugin to include the snippet.